# Is it possible to treat Flex' events in a synchronous way?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I'm using flex4 and actionscript, and need to treat an event in a synchronous mode. Is it possible that? More exactly, i want to execute some queries in a database, and need to be synchronously. Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by treat event synchronously? more explanation would be great!

Comment: for example i want to query my database by a urlLoader : URLLoader:

code : urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
       urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE .....);

Ok. When the program encounter urlLoader.load(...) line, i want it to handle this operation, and only after everithing is done to go away. But i want to do that outside of listener function (the function that is called when urlLoader completes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. The FlashPlayer execution model doesn't allow that. If you really need to do that a lot, I suggest you create a domain specific markup/scripting language, or create a library to help arranging the code in a concise, clear and linear manner ([eaze](http://code.google.com/p/eaze-tween/) demonstrates, how you can do that with chaining).

greetz
back2dos